# Mostrar datos de sql server con LINQ en un div ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, webforms

ASP.NET C# JAVASCRIPT

Hola buenas, Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion web donde puedas guardar notas con categorias de materias y mi intencion es mostrar el titulo, descripcion y materia en la misma pagina y guardarlo en la BD de sqlserver cada vez que se presione el boton de guardar.

Tengo esta tabla en sql server 2018
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego los datos desde mi pagina, desde este formulario:

Lo que necesito hacer es mostrar especificamente los campos {Titulo} y {Descripcion} en este div:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui está mi codigo:

```
<!-- NOTAS EN PAGINA -->
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div id="tasks" runat="server">
                        <div class="card mb-3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold"><big>${Titulo}</big> - <span class="badge badge-primary">${Categoria}</span></p>
                                <p> ${Descripcion}
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="editTask('${tt}, ${ta}')" class="btn btn-success">Editar</a>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="" class="btn btn-info">Materia</a>
                                    <a href="#" onclick="deleteTask('${tt}')" class="btn btn-danger ml-5">Delete</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Titulo es un textbox, descripcion es un textarea y categorias es un dropdownlist

Lo guardo desde este metodo:

```
public void saveNote()
        {
            Notas objnote = new Notas();
            objnote.Titulo = title.Text;
            string getTxtA = Request.Form["description"];
            objnote.Descripcion = getTxtA;
            //Variable session ----------------------------
            string usuario = Request.QueryString["usuario"];
            LblUser.Text = usuario;
            //set
            objnote.NombreUser = usuario;
            //------------------------------------
            objnote.NombreMateria = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            noteBD.Notas.InsertOnSubmit(objnote);
            noteBD.SubmitChanges();

            limpiar();

            
        }
```

Y este es mi esquema de LINQ
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: necesitas importarte los datos desde el controlador, necesitaria saber como lo guardas para poder ayudarte mas

Comment: Gracias, he editado la pregunta añadiendo como guardo la nota

Comment: y has comprobado si te guarda los datos? respecto a tu duda, para importar los datos necesitar realizar un get que te los importe desde el back, se como hacerlo en mvc pero no estoy seguro si es en lo que lo estas desarrollando